# How to check the android mobile phone whether it turns into AP mode or not?

Tags: java, android, access-point

everyone~
I have a problem to solve.
 
I want to use java code to check whether the android mobile phone turns into AP mode or not?
I use google engine to search related information, but I didn't find any related issue.
I hope that this problem could be solved.
Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Is AP mode you are reffering as Airplane Mode?

Comment: Oh~The AP mode which I said is "Access Point". Thank you for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

i found a snipped to do this

```
private class TetherChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context content, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.ACTION_TETHER_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            // TODO - this should understand the interface types
            ArrayList<String> available = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_TETHER);
            ArrayList<String> active = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_ACTIVE_TETHER);

            ArrayList<String> errored = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_ERRORED_TETHER);

        }

    }

}
```

apparently only on Android 2.3

Comment: I use Android 2.2 to develop my app, but thank you for your help:)